Session state variable not staying
I have session states in my project, that'll hold either brand name, city, state, zip, and cached when clicking on a link to go back the home page. Currently it doesn't save the session and show the table. Not sure where I went wrong any help is appreciated.
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("search_Returning") == "1")
        {
            //If the session variables are filled, then load from there; otherwise, set default values.
            search.BrandName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("search_BrandName")??"") ? HttpContext.Session.GetString("search_BrandName")! : "";
            search.City = string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("search_City") ?? "") ? HttpContext.Session.GetString("search_City")! : "";
            search.State = string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("search_State") ?? "") ? HttpContext.Session.GetString("search_State")! : "";
            search.PostalCode = string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("search_Zip") ?? "") ? HttpContext.Session.GetString("search_Zip")! : "";
            search.Cached = string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("search_Cached")) ? false : true;
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("search_Returning", "0");
        }


The logic shown is a bit confusing, but... It looks like you're only displaying the session values if they're empty?  Can you replicate the problem with a simpler example which demonstrates only the use of session values and doesn't include your other logic?

Could you also add startup code?

I have successfully setup using session variables with new clean ASP.NET application. I can only say that you need to pay attention to register needed services in startup code. Here's simple example that I got to work:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Below services are needed for using sessions.
builder.Services.AddDataProtection();
builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

// This middleware is needed for sessions.
app.UseSession();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext httpContext) =>
{
    var s = httpContext.Session.GetString("search_Returning");
    httpContext.Session.SetString("search_Returning", "0123");
})
.WithOpenApi();

app.Run();

